# What is the pattern of navigating between UIViewControllers in iOS?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, navigation

I have a bunch of `UIViewController`s subclasses (let's call them `MainForm`, `DetailForm`, `MoreMinorDetails`).  Basically the idea is that `AppDelegate` class instantiates `MainForm`, user presses some type of button on `MainForm` and `DetailForm` comes up. Then on a button on the `DetailForm` launches `MoreMinorDetails`. And of course, I should be able to go back down to the `MainForm`.

Note that there aren't any `UINavigationController` objects anywhere in sight.
What is the accepted pattern to move between `UIViewController`s in a manner described above?

Or am I going about it in the wrong way?
I'll be happy with either XCode or MonoTouch based explanation.

Comment: Why are there no navigation controllers in sight? Navigation controller is precisely the standard way to solve this problem.

Comment: @zoul Because, as I understand it (I might be totally wrong), the second screen would need a back button on the nav bar.  I have no space for it, as I have the + and Edit buttons there.

Comment: Move the + button to a toolbar or make it a button somewhere in your view. You're going to have to have a button for navigation, and for a navigation controller that's the back button.

Comment: You can use the UINavigationController without the navigationBar. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `UINavigationController` and hide the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Then in your button's action just push the next view controller:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

To go back, use

```
-(void)goBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To go to a certain view controller (you have to know exactly when it was pushed onto the navigation controller's stack):

```
-(void)goToViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}
```

Or to pop to your root view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This way, you will obtain the `UINavigationController`'s functionality and keep all the space in the view.

Answer (score 1):

AngryHacker,

My simple suggestion is to follow **zoul** one. I think the simplest way to achieve what you want it' to create a `UINavigationController` and use it as a containment controller for other controllers.

So, the way could be create a `UINavigationController` in the `AppDelegate` and set it as the `rootViewController` for your `window`. When you create a `UINavigationController` you can pass to it a root controller (in this case `MainForm`).

In MT it looks like the following (do not trust the code because I've written it by hand)

```
private UINavigationController navController;
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    navController = new UINavigationController(new MainForm());
    window.RootViewController = navController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

Now, when you launch the app you will see the `MainForm`'s view and will able to allow navigation among different controllers.

For example, within `MainForm` you can go to `DetailForm` like:

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new DetailForm(), true);
```

The same applies within `DetailForm` to `MoreMinorDetails`.

To go one step back, for example from `MoreMinorDetails` to `DetailForm` use

```
this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(false);
```

To go to the the root controller (`MainForm`) within `DetailForm` or `MoreMinorDetails` use

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewControllerAnimated(false);
```

About the space, it's not a problem. I guess you have two ways. The first is to move the bar items you have created within the navigation controller bar. In each controller you can decide what buttons make visible or not. The second is to hide completely the navigation bar and use the button you've already created.

In both ways you can attach actions to these buttons and allow the navigation between controllers. Furthermore, if you choose the first you can also hide the back button for your navigation bar.

*A simple note to take in mind is the following:*

Since the navigation bar is unique for a `UINavigationController`, the bar will maintains its state for all the controllers you push in the navigation controller. To explain the concept suppose you have two controllers, say A and B. You first push A and in its `ViewWillAppear` method you hide a button. When you push B, the button still remains not visible. If you want to unhide the button in B, you can play with its `ViewWillAppear` method (like before) and so on...

If you don't want to play with `UINavigationController` you should take a look to new view controller containment functionality provided by `UIViewController` class. This applies only from iOS >= 5. You can obtain the same effect of `UINavigationController` mechanism but it could be more difficult to achieve.

Hope that helps.